# Error with Pen C#

Tags: c#, pen

I did a system to select an area using the mouse.
However, when I select the area looks like:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xxc0ayn.png]

Sorry my english, i'm brazilian...

My Code:

```
    private void ResizeSelection()
    {

        if (CurrentAction == ClickAction.LeftSizing)
        {

            if (Cursor.Position.X < CurrentBottomRight.X - 10)
            {

                //Erase the previous rectangle
                g.DrawRectangle(EraserPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);
                CurrentTopLeft.X = Cursor.Position.X;
                RectangleWidth = CurrentBottomRight.X - CurrentTopLeft.X;
                g.DrawRectangle(MyPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);

            }

        }
        if (CurrentAction == ClickAction.TopLeftSizing)
        {

            if (Cursor.Position.X < CurrentBottomRight.X - 10 && Cursor.Position.Y < CurrentBottomRight.Y - 10)
            {

                //Erase the previous rectangle
                g.DrawRectangle(EraserPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);
                CurrentTopLeft.X = Cursor.Position.X;
                CurrentTopLeft.Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
                RectangleWidth = CurrentBottomRight.X - CurrentTopLeft.X;
                RectangleHeight = CurrentBottomRight.Y - CurrentTopLeft.Y;
                g.DrawRectangle(MyPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);

            }
        }
        if (CurrentAction == ClickAction.BottomLeftSizing)
        {

            if (Cursor.Position.X < CurrentBottomRight.X - 10 && Cursor.Position.Y > CurrentTopLeft.Y + 10)
            {

                //Erase the previous rectangle
                g.DrawRectangle(EraserPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);
                CurrentTopLeft.X = Cursor.Position.X;
                CurrentBottomRight.Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
                RectangleWidth = CurrentBottomRight.X - CurrentTopLeft.X;
                RectangleHeight = CurrentBottomRight.Y - CurrentTopLeft.Y;
                g.DrawRectangle(MyPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);

            }

        }
        if (CurrentAction == ClickAction.RightSizing)
        {

            if (Cursor.Position.X > CurrentTopLeft.X + 10)
            {

                //Erase the previous rectangle
                g.DrawRectangle(EraserPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);
                CurrentBottomRight.X = Cursor.Position.X;
                RectangleWidth = CurrentBottomRight.X - CurrentTopLeft.X;
                g.DrawRectangle(MyPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);

            }
        }
        if (CurrentAction == ClickAction.TopRightSizing)
        {

            if (Cursor.Position.X > CurrentTopLeft.X + 10 && Cursor.Position.Y < CurrentBottomRight.Y - 10)
            {

                //Erase the previous rectangle
                g.DrawRectangle(EraserPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);
                CurrentBottomRight.X = Cursor.Position.X;
                CurrentTopLeft.Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
                RectangleWidth = CurrentBottomRight.X - CurrentTopLeft.X;
                RectangleHeight = CurrentBottomRight.Y - CurrentTopLeft.Y;
                g.DrawRectangle(MyPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);

            }
        }
        if (CurrentAction == ClickAction.BottomRightSizing)
        {

            if (Cursor.Position.X > CurrentTopLeft.X + 10 && Cursor.Position.Y > CurrentTopLeft.Y + 10)
            {

                //Erase the previous rectangle
                g.DrawRectangle(EraserPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);
                CurrentBottomRight.X = Cursor.Position.X;
                CurrentBottomRight.Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
                RectangleWidth = CurrentBottomRight.X - CurrentTopLeft.X;
                RectangleHeight = CurrentBottomRight.Y - CurrentTopLeft.Y;
                g.DrawRectangle(MyPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);

            }
        }
        if (CurrentAction == ClickAction.TopSizing)
        {

            if (Cursor.Position.Y < CurrentBottomRight.Y - 10)
            {

                //Erase the previous rectangle
                g.DrawRectangle(EraserPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);
                CurrentTopLeft.Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
                RectangleHeight = CurrentBottomRight.Y - CurrentTopLeft.Y;
                g.DrawRectangle(MyPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);

            }
        }
        if (CurrentAction == ClickAction.BottomSizing)
        {

            if (Cursor.Position.Y > CurrentTopLeft.Y + 10)
            {

                //Erase the previous rectangle
                g.DrawRectangle(EraserPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);
                CurrentBottomRight.Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
                RectangleHeight = CurrentBottomRight.Y - CurrentTopLeft.Y;
                g.DrawRectangle(MyPen, CurrentTopLeft.X, CurrentTopLeft.Y, RectangleWidth, RectangleHeight);

            }

        }

    }
```

I wonder if there is a way to fix this or make it become transparent showing only the edge of the rectangle.
Thanks,

Comment: Is there a `g.Clear()` function you could call to clear the screen of your rectangles before the current one is redrawn?

Comment: No, I tested it. it leaves the entire screen of black using Color.Transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mis-using `Graphics`.

You should never call `CreateGraphics()` to draw on a control; it will be erased on the next paint.

Instead, you should handle the `Paint` event and draw everything you need on every repaint.

When the mouse moves, call `Invalidate()` to force it to repaint.

Comment: Thus delete the rectangle when I re-select, it should remain and increase necessary to and not be recreated.

Comment: @MarlonRobertoColhado: You need to redraw _everything_ on each `Paint` event.  Store a list of things to draw in a `List<T>`.  If you don't do this, things will vanish randomly.

Comment: I took a modified in eraser, got this: http://i.imgur.com/tQWY3xT.png However, some things are missed, letters inside the rectangle, it would make the eraser to create a color with transparency after the red pen? or opacity in eraser..

Comment: @MarlonRobertoColhado: Yes; that's because you're still doing it wrong.  **You need to move all of this to a `Paint` handler.**

Comment: I do not know how I can do this. :/

Comment: I'll send you all my code to better understand what is happening: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68327673/RemotePrintUpload.rar

Comment: @MarlonRobertoColhado: What don't you understand?

Comment: Got it, changed the TransparentKey to: 255, 255, 192  And PenEraser to: Pen EraserPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192), 3.0F);  Result: http://i.imgur.com/QNQZqQ3.png (Thanks anyway.) :D